# Factoring out a fraction from an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm working through some practice problems with partial fractions and after working through the final answer, I am very confused by this posted solution:

> \begin{align}
> \int \frac{11x-7}{2x^2-3x-2} \, dx &= \int \frac 5{2x+1} \, dx + \int \frac 3{x-2} \, dx \\
> &= \frac 52 \ln |2x+1|+3\ln|x-2|+C
> \end{align}

I got the $3\ln|x-2|$ part right, but I didn't get the $\frac 52 \ln|2x+1|$ part. I am confused by where the $\frac 52$ comes from. I got $5\ln|2x+1|$.

I guess my question is, if the $2$ from $2x + 1$ is factored out to divide $5$ by, wouldn't it not remain in the ln function? Wouldn't the result be $\frac 52 \ln|x+1|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\int \frac{5}{2x+1}dx=\frac52\int\frac{2}{2x+1}dx=\frac{5}{2}\ln\vert 2x+1\vert+C$$

Comment: But why does 2 get to remain in the numerator? If you factor out the 5, can't only 1 remain in the numerator?

Comment: Actually, nothing has changed, because $\frac52\cdot\frac21=5$. @zavtra

Comment: Ah, but why the insistence on keeping the 2x+1 in the denominator? I just feel that if 2 is being factored out, it shouldn't be there anymore.

Comment: It is not factored out, it is because of the substitution u=2x+1 resulting in an extra half.

Comment: OOOHHH. Wow the solution doesn't even show a u substitution everywhere. I forgot about that part. I didn't even realize. I was confused where the 2 was coming from at all. Thank you.

Comment: At this point the teacher usually thinks that you can do simple u-substitutions in your head. After all, it is a Calc I technique.

Comment: I didn't take calc 1 for several years.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \dfrac{5}{2x+1}dx$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int \dfrac{5}{u}$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}*5\ln|u|$$

$$=\dfrac{5}{2}\ln|u|$$